# Generated PDF Bold Text looks blurry. Looks precise when zoomed in

Tags: itext7

I am facing an issue while using iText 7 for generating PDF which has text:

1. Text Looks blurry
2. If zoomed in text looks fine.
3. I have tried generating text by applying custom fonts as well but no affect.

Can anyone help with same?
Blurry Text really makes the PDF Unreadable.

Comment: Please share the pivotal code and a result PDF. And tell us in which browser at which screen resolution and zoom factor you get the blur.

Comment: Do not use `setBold()` (and read the documentation), and use the genuine bold font instead